# NgRx selectors with parameters are failing unit tests

Tags: angular, jasmine, ngrx

I'm testing if my store selector functions are being called correctly in my ngOnInit() method, and my selectors with parameters are failing tests my selectors without parameters are passing (failing tests are commented in code sample, they are the last two). The error message  `Expected $[0] = Function to equal Function` isn't helpful for me. Some insight to why this might be happening or just general test debugging tips for ngrx would be appreciated.

Please let me know if any more code is needed.

**Spec.ts**

```
    fdescribe('OpenOrderAddComponent', () => {
      let component: OpenOrderAddComponent;
      let fixture: ComponentFixture<OpenOrderAddComponent>;
      const modalSpy: jasmine.Spy = jasmine.createSpyObj('ModalController', ['create']);

      beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
          declarations: [OpenOrderAddComponent],
          schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
          providers: [
            provideMockStore({
              initialState: INITIAL_APP_STATE()
            }),
            { provide: ModalController, useValue: modalSpy },
          ]
        }).compileComponents();

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(OpenOrderAddComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
      }));

      it('should create', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
      });

      describe('on ngOnInit', () => {
        let store: any;
        beforeEach(() => {
          store = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(Store);
          spyOn(store, 'select').and.callThrough();
          component.documentId = 'fakeid';
          component.ngOnInit();
          fixture.detectChanges();
        });

        it('should call select 3 different times', () => {
          expect(store.select).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(3); // succeeds
        });
        it('should select searched items ids', () => {
          expect(store.select.calls.allArgs()[1]).toEqual([getSearchedItemsIds]) // succeeds
        });
        // FAILING TESTS BELOW
        it('should select open order lines', () => {
          expect(store.select.calls.allArgs()[2]).toEqual([getOpenOrderLines(component.documentId)])
          // fails with error: Expected $[0] = Function to equal Function.
        });
        it('should select open order modifications', () => {
          expect(store.select.calls.allArgs()[3]).toEqual([getOpenOrderModifications(component.documentId)])
          // fails with error: Expected $[0] = Function to equal Function.
        });
    });
});
```

**component.ts ngOnInit() code**

```
ngOnInit(){    
    this.itemIds$ = this.store.select(getSearchedItemsIds);
    this.store.select(getOpenOrderLines(this.documentId)).subscribe(openOrderLines => {...});
    this.store.select(getOpenOrderModifications(this.documentId)).subscribe(orderModifications =>{...});
}
```

**selectors**

```
export const getSearchedItemsIds = createSelector(
  selectSearch,
  selectItems,
  selectCartLines,
  (searchState, items): string[] => {
    return searchState.search
      .map((itemId: string) => items[itemId].ItemID);
  }
);

export const getOpenOrderLines = (documentId: string) => createSelector(
  selectOpenOrderItems(documentId),
  (orderItems?: OpenOrderItem[]) => {
    return orderItems ? orderItems : undefined;
  }
);

export const getOpenOrderModifications = (documentId: string) => createSelector(
  selectOrderModifications(documentId),
  (orderModifications: OpenOrderModification[]) => {
    return orderModifications;
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this, !! is placed for stuff that requires your attention:

```
   fdescribe('OpenOrderAddComponent', () => {
      let component: OpenOrderAddComponent;
      let fixture: ComponentFixture<OpenOrderAddComponent>;
      const modalSpy: jasmine.Spy = jasmine.createSpyObj('ModalController', ['create']);

      beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
          declarations: [OpenOrderAddComponent],
          schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
          providers: [
            provideMockStore({
              initialState: INITIAL_APP_STATE()
            }),
            { provide: ModalController, useValue: modalSpy },
          ]
        }).compileComponents();

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(OpenOrderAddComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
      }));

      it('should create', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
      });

      describe('on ngOnInit', () => {
        let store: any;
        beforeEach(() => {
          store = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(Store);
          spyOn(store, 'select').and.callThrough();
          component.documentId = 'fakeid';
          // component.ngOnInit(); => No need to call `ngOnInit here, the `fixture.detechChanges() below does it for you. Calling it twice can make your assertions fail.
          fixture.detectChanges();
        });

        it('should call select 3 different times', () => {
          expect(store.select).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(3); // succeeds
        });
        it('should select searched items ids', () => {
          expect(store.select.calls.allArgs()[1]).toEqual([getSearchedItemsIds]) // succeeds
        });
        // FAILING TESTS BELOW
        it('should select open order lines', () => {

       expect(store.select).toHaveBeenCalledWith(getOpenOrderLines(component.documentId));
          // !! ^^
          // fails with error: Expected $[0] = Function to equal Function.
        });
        it('should select open order modifications', () => {
          expect(store.select).toHaveBeenCalledWith(getOpenOrderModifications(component.documentId));
          // ^^
          // fails with error: Expected $[0] = Function to equal Function.
        });
    });
});
```

But I wouldn't be asserting that `store.select` was called with this or that argument. I would be testing what goes on in the `subscribe` block of each `select`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That was my original method, but the error I would get from that was `expected [ Function ] but actual calls were [ Function ], [ Function ], [ Function ].` Ever ran into that before?

Comment: I have not ran into that before. If I were you, like I mentioned previously, I would test what happens inside of the `subscribes` and not what the select was selected with.

Comment: Okay thanks. Why would you test what happens in the subscribe rather than what I'm trying to test?

Comment: Because the `subscribe` is what should change instance variables and update the view. Doing it this way you're actually testing the implementation and if you're testing the subscribe, you get the tests you want for free. If it made it to the subscribe, of course `store.select` was called with the selector you are concerned about.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you for the explanation.